# SQL replace query for variable content

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a SQL query to clean up a hacked SQL Server database. I have some basic SQL knowledge, but I have no idea how to solve the below.

For one of our websites we have a SQL Server database that was recently hacked into. Thousands of records were filled with hidden divs, containing all sorts of dodgy references. Our ISP says the content of the database is not their responsibility and they have no knowledge how to help us clean up the database. There are no clean backups available. It is way too much work to go through all records manually.

So I am now desperately trying to find a SQL query to remove these blocks of hidden text from the database.

Two useful bits of information:

1. All the spammy content is contained within div tags. The information between the tags is different in every instance, but they all open and close with the div tag.
2. Our original data will have some HTML-content, but will never contain div tags. So if we can find a way to remove everything from the starting div up to and including the closing div, then we would be sorted.

Any assistance here is much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Before you get much further along you need to go back to your code and fix the sql injection vulnerability. When you do build up a string containing content from the user without parameters your code is vulnerable. I know it seems backwards but you probably need to fix that before fixing the data. Most times when somebody finds that exploit they just keep doing it so any data cleanup is pointless as it will just get defaced again. Once that is done you can start the cleanup.

Comment: The cleanup is going to be fun in its own right. You will have to get really familiar with substring, patindex and charindex.

Comment: No idea what programming language your site is in but this site has some basics for preventing sql injection in many languages. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Also, once you're back in business, back up your databases regularly. Please.

Comment: One thing you could do. Since you say that NONE of your code has divs, you could add a class to your sites styles sheet to hide all divs. Just add [div]{display:none;}. Note that if you have any other divs anywhere on your site they will be hidden.

Comment: @SeanLange - That'd still be exposing potentially malicious links to the client/browser.

Comment: I realize that, but it would hide them until they can fix the code to prevent it from coming back. It would be a stop gap at best for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies, @SeanLange. The site is running on (*blush) classic ASP. Unfortunately Bobby Tables doesn't seem to offer much on that front. But I will dig into the SQL injection prevention; good point.

Comment: Oh @SeanLange, what I didn't mention originally is that these are in fact already hidden divs. So it is not directly defacing the website, but it is of course being indexed and is showing up in Google results.

Comment: @JeffreyVanLaethem, thanks also for your input. You are of course correct. We do actually have a backup, but unfortunately this also contains the divs. Because they are hidden, it took quite some time for us to notice them. :[

Comment: I feel your pain about classic ASP. We still have some of those running around too. This quick search will reveal that you are by far not alone in needing to deal with that annoying bobby tables and his mayhem in classic asp. https://www.google.com/search?q=parameterized+queries+in+classic+asp&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Thanks for the link! I hadn't thought about this being the root of the problem. Will look into this and try to close this path asap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out; will only work if your assumptions are correct. Another assumption hacker did not add nested DIVs. And yes, TEST this thoroughly before running the update. And back up your data before running the update.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(id INT IDENTITY, html VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT #temp(html)
VALUES('<p>Some text</p><strong>other text</strong><div>added by hacker</div>')
,('<p>Some text</p><strong>other text<div>added by hacker within html tag</div></strong>')
,('<p>Some text</p><div>some other text added by <a href="http://google.com">hack</a></div><strong>other text</strong>');


SELECT html
,  CHARINDEX('<div',html) AS startPos
, CHARINDEX('</div>',html) AS endPos
, (CHARINDEX('</div>',html)+6)-(CHARINDEX('<div',html)) AS stringLenToRemove
, SUBSTRING(html, CHARINDEX('<div',html), (CHARINDEX('</div>',html)+6)-(CHARINDEX('<div',html))) AS HtmlAddedByHack
,REPLACE(html,SUBSTRING(html, CHARINDEX('<div',html), (CHARINDEX('</div>',html)+6)-(CHARINDEX('<div',html))), '') AS sanitizedHtml
FROM #temp;

--UPDATE #temp
--SET html = REPLACE(html,SUBSTRING(html, CHARINDEX('<div',html), (CHARINDEX('</div>',html)+6)-(CHARINDEX('<div',html))), '');

--SELECT  *
--FROM    #temp;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, DK. Out of the code suggestions received so far this is the only one that I can actually understand :] It looks pretty logical and is along the lines I was thinking. I will give this one a try and will let you know.

Comment: Hi DK, I have been experimenting with the above and have been able to get this code to produce results. What I am running now is this:

Comment: `SELECT tekst
, CHARINDEX('<div',tekst) AS startPos
, CHARINDEX('</div>',tekst) AS endPos
, (CHARINDEX('</div>',tekst)+6)-(CHARINDEX('<div',tekst)) AS stringLenToRemove
, SUBSTRING(tekst, CHARINDEX('<div',tekst), (CHARINDEX('</div>',tekst)+6)-(CHARINDEX('<div',tekst))) AS HtmlAddedByHack
FROM [xxx].[dbo].[xxx] WHERE id =1

UPDATE [xxx].[dbo].[xxx]
SET tekst = REPLACE(tekst,SUBSTRING(tekst, CHARINDEX('<div',tekst), (CHARINDEX('</div>',tekst)+6)-(CHARINDEX('<div',tekst))), '') WHERE id =1;`

Comment: As you can see I am limiting the query to one record for testing purposes. 

What happens is that it looks through the record for the first instance of the div and then succesfully removes it. There are two problems though: 

1) the records contain multiple instances (but I can run the query multiple times to take them all out); 

2) when I repeat the query, at some point it runs out of divs and starts deleting the first six characters of the record (presumably from the +6 in the code).

How can I tell the query to not delete anything when there are no more div's?

Comment: you can add a where clause to ensure only rows that have the issue are cleaned: WHERE html like '%<div>%'
and html like '%</div>%'

Comment: Thanks, that sounds completely logical and easy. Will give that a go. How do I then get it to loop through the entire database without having to click for every single instance of the div?

Comment: Do you mean to say every table/column in the database? You can loop thro all columns in all tables and create a dynamic sql and then execute the dynamic sql. But I would be very careful in doing this. Would recommend you restore the database to a separate instance; perform your changes, test it out and then swap out the databases.

Comment: My apologies; I meant looping through the table, not the entire database. I made a copy of the table and am working with that. I have roughly 5,500 records that I need to loop through and am having some trouble keeping the coding efficient. What I have now is this: http://pastebin.com/bM0Aj9gs. It goes to record one, does the cleanup four times and then goes to record two does four cleanup rounds etc. When I limited it to 1000 records it ran for close to an hour last night though and it still wasn't finished then. Is there anything I can do to clean this up/make it more efficient?

Comment: I was trying to include a statement along the lines of 'IF stringLenToRemove > 0 THEN <do the cleanup thing>'. That should trim down the unnecessary loops considerably. But I couldn't get it working as the code was not recognizing stringLenToRemove as a record. Any tips how to do that IF-statement in SQL?

Comment: Why do you need to update 1 record at a time? Just run the update with the where clause to check if <div are found. And you can run the update couple of times till 0 records are updated.

Comment: Because I made some wrong assumptions about the way the script works :)  I removed that part and included a clause to prevent an error when CHARINDEX gives a negative result; now it works. I have only 292 infected records left (on a total of 5.600), so nearly there. In that last set I am getting this error: 'String or binary data would be truncated.' Google tells me that is because I am trying to paste too much data into a small field. But this is a memo-type field and I don't see how this script would make the data any bigger. Any ideas? This is the current code: http://pastebin.com/y2Tg5XMZ

Comment: thats weird...do you get the error even on select or only on update? whats the field type for "html"

Comment: Yes, it does the same on just running the select. I get two errors when I run select and update (and it doesn't update anything). The field type is nvarchar. Which is exactly the same as a second column that I ran the entire code on without a single error.

Answer (score 1):

A UDF that uses `PATINDEX` may be able to do it.

Assuming

- All malicious content is in `<DIV>...</DIV>` sections
- No `<DIV>...</DIV>` sections exist that are *not* malicious content
- You TEST THIS EXTENSIVELY on a backup of your data before applying it to your live database

First use this UDF for Pattern replacement, from [here](http://dataeducation.com/splitting-a-string-of-unlimited-length/):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PatternReplace
(
   @InputString VARCHAR(4000),
   @Pattern VARCHAR(100),
   @ReplaceText VARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(4000) SET @Result = ''
   -- First character in a match
   DECLARE @First INT
   -- Next character to start search on
   DECLARE @Next INT SET @Next = 1
   -- Length of the total string -- 8001 if @InputString is NULL
   DECLARE @Len INT SET @Len = COALESCE(LEN(@InputString), 8001)
   -- End of a pattern
   DECLARE @EndPattern INT

   WHILE (@Next <= @Len) 
   BEGIN
      SET @First = PATINDEX('%' + @Pattern + '%', SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @Len))
      IF COALESCE(@First, 0) = 0 --no match - return
      BEGIN
         SET @Result = @Result + 
            CASE --return NULL, just like REPLACE, if inputs are NULL
               WHEN  @InputString IS NULL
                     OR @Pattern IS NULL
                     OR @ReplaceText IS NULL THEN NULL
               ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @Len)
            END
         BREAK
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
         -- Concatenate characters before the match to the result
         SET @Result = @Result + SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @First - 1)
         SET @Next = @Next + @First - 1

         SET @EndPattern = 1
         -- Find start of end pattern range
         WHILE PATINDEX(@Pattern, SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @EndPattern)) = 0
            SET @EndPattern = @EndPattern + 1
         -- Find end of pattern range
         WHILE PATINDEX(@Pattern, SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @EndPattern)) > 0
               AND @Len >= (@Next + @EndPattern - 1)
            SET @EndPattern = @EndPattern + 1

         --Either at the end of the pattern or @Next + @EndPattern = @Len
         SET @Result = @Result + @ReplaceText
         SET @Next = @Next + @EndPattern - 1
      END
   END
   RETURN(@Result)
END
```

Then, make use of the UDF:

```
UPDATE ContentTable SET ContentColumn=dbo.PatternReplace('<DIV>%</DIV>', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a cursor like this ....

```
Declare @ColumnName sysname , @TableName sysname 
        ,@Schema sysname , @Sql Nvarchar(MAX);

Declare Cur CURSOR FOR 
Select c.name , t.name , s.name
from sys.columns c 
inner join sys.tables  t on c.object_id = t.object_id
inner join sys.types   p on p.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
inner join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where t.is_ms_shipped = 0
and p.name in ('varchar','nvarchar', 'char', 'nchar')

OPEN Cur 

 FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @ColumnName , @TableName , @Schema

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    SET @Sql = N'UPDATE '+ QUOTENAME(@Schema) +'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) 
             + N' SET ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N' = '
             + N'LEFT(' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N', CHARINDEX(''<div>'', 
                          ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N') - 1) 
                      + SUBSTRING(' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N', 
                      CHARINDEX(''</div>'', ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N') + 6
                      , LEN(' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N'))
                Where ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N' IS NOT NULL 
                AND LEN(' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N') > 6' 

     Exec sp_executesql @Sql 

     FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @ColumnName , @TableName , @Schema
END 

CLOSE Cur 
DEALLOCATE Cur
```

**Note**

The cursor loops through all the tables and select columns with `varchar , nvarchar, char ,nchar` data types, then it creates an update statement to strip out any string between `<div> </div>` tags thats if it exists, else column is left as it is.

**Warning**

Test the script before you actually run it against the live database.